# Is there a way to use promise with custom validation on semantic ui

Tags: javascript, validation, semantic-ui

Is there any way to use promise with a custom rule on semantic ui?
I want to validate a field with my custom rule. If response of server is false field must be red.
Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
$.fn.form.settings.rules.myCustomRule = function(param) {
let myPromise = this.get('api').r_get(allUrls.urlName, model);
  myPromise.then(
    response => {
        return true;
    }
  ).catch(
    error => {
        return false;
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `error` class to a div or input when the promise returns false. Would that work? Like this:

```js
function simulateServer(){
  $('#serverresponse').addClass('error');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="serverresponse" class="ui input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</div>

<br><br>
<button onclick="simulateServer()">Contact Server</button>
```

It wouldn't be possible with a custom rule promise, as it expects an immediate response.

Comment: I have checked source code the delay time is 200ms. Thank you for your interest. I just want to sure is there any way to manage without manuel css manipulation.